# Binding controls to specific members of a list (.net, c#, win forms)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, list, binding

This is my first post and I am pretty new to programming so I  sorry if this question is stupid or answered elsewhere. I have been searching for days but may simply not have a sufficient grasp of the terminology to find my question.

I am attempting to figure out usage of .NET 4.5 with C# in a simple winforms application. I have list (deviceList) of custom objects  (device). Each of these devices contains a bool property (State). I would like to have a checkBox whose checked status is bound to one the State of each Device in the deviceList. Is this possible?

As far as I can tell, I can link to the list, but each of the checkboxes bound to the list will instead show the state of the current member of the list.

Edit: Answered provided below
I simply need to reference the specific index of the item in the list rather than the entire list.

`DataBindings.Add("Checked", items[i], "IsActive");`

Comment: Can you show some of the code you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use something like:

```
myControl.DataBindings.Add("ControlProperty", dataSource, "DataSourceProperty");
```

to bind a control to a specific property of a data source.  More often than not, the data source is a list of some kind and the control represents the state of the specified property for the item currently selected in that list.

The data source doesn't have to be a list though.  It can be an object where `DataSourceProperty` is a property of that object rather than of items in a list.  If you have N items in a list and N `CheckBoxes` then you simply bind each `CheckBox` directly to an item rather than to the list, e.g.

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
{
    checkBoxes[i].DataBindings.Add("Checked", items[i], "IsActive");
}
```